# typecast variable by specifying desired type as a variable of it's own

Tags: php, casting

I have an object ($result), and I'm using a separate array as a lookup table, to map the properties to the correct type (int, bool, string, etc.)

What I'd like to do is loop through the array and cast each property to the correct type, ideally as cleanly as possible without a complicated switch statement. So… why won't this work?

```
// where $type = "int", "bool" etc.
$result->{$key} = ($type) $result->{$key};
```

> syntax error, unexpected '$result'

(PhpStorm just says "expected semi-colon" after the closing bracket of $type)

Comment: It does not work, because this type-cast syntax is a language construct, and you can not simply replace the type with a variable. That’s how `$foo 'bar';` does not work either, just because `$foo` might contain the text `echo` … You would actually have to eval this to make that work.

Comment: You might want to look into [`settype`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.settype.php) – _that_ takes the type to set as a string parameter.

Comment: What is this resulting object? `stdClass`? Something custom? What do you have to turn that `$result` into that requires precise type casting?

Comment: @CBroe superb, thank you.